# Doubly Linked List

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

How do i swap the content of the nodes within doubly linked list randomly. No need to change the nodes but only the contents of the nodes. I managed to get random numbers to identify the number of cards based on the for loop in this case is 4. However i am stuck when i want to swap the their contents... Anyone can help?

I created a deck class:

```
public class Deck {

DoublyLinkedList<Card> mainDeck = new DoublyLinkedList<>();

String[] ranks = {"A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Joker", "Queen", "King"};
String[] suits = {"Club", "Spade", "Diamond", "Heart"};

public Deck() {
    for (String suit : suits) {
        for (String rank : ranks) {
            this.mainDeck.insertFirst(new Card(suit, rank));

        }
    }

}

public DoublyLinkedList<Card> getDeck() {
    return mainDeck;
}

public void swap() {
    Random generator = new Random();
    Card temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int index1 = generator.nextInt(mainDeck.getSize() - 1);
        int index2 = generator.nextInt(mainDeck.getSize() - 1);
        temp = (Card)mainDeck.
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Edit the question and post the code in it, questions and answers need to stand on their own. Links die over time.

Comment: Since you have no methods for retrieving a card by index, you cannot. You might want to add method `swap(int index1, int index2)` to your list.

Comment: Exactly what im thinking. How do i create a method for retrieving a card by index? @Andreas

Comment: You know how to write a full doubly linked list class, but can't figure out how to iterate the linked nodes to find the N'th node?

Comment: I do, but the object classes add a lot of weight to it. @Andreas

Comment: Also, if you implement `T get(int index)`, then your swap logic will be very slow, because it has to iterate list to find it, iterate the list again to remove it, and iterate the list yet again to add it. Too many iterations. Implement `swap(int index1, int index2)`, which internally iterates twice to find the two nodes, then just swap the node `data` values. List links remain unchanged. Must faster that way.

Comment: Don't understand comment "add a lot of weight". How does iterating the linked nodes, the same way you do it in `displayForward()`, to find the N'th node, add "weight"?

Answer (score 0):

No need to roll your own doubly linked list, there already is [one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

If you must use your own, then you could implement `List` as; if you use a `List` implementation such as the build in doubly linked list, [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), you can use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)):

```
LinkedList<Card> list = ...
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

And I would use supply my own [random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List,%20java.util.Random)):

```
Collections.shuffle(list, new SecureRandom());
```

Comment: You must put the code in the question. Google docs or any external location is not acceptable.

Comment: OP's `DoublyLinkedList` class does not implement `List`, so [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) won't work. --- Also, shuffling deck of cards hardly need to be secure. Standard `Random` is perfectly fine for that.

Comment: @Andreas I had no code to look at and no reason to think they had rolled their own doubly linked list. I'll update to recommend they use what's there.

Comment: @ClarkKent Was this any help to you? Please upvote or accept helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need two temporary variables to point to the two objects in the doubly linked list (ex. object1 and object2) that you wish to swap. You first do a search through the list for the first object you want to swap (iterate through the list starting with the head object until you find an object that has the value or id that matches the one of the objects you wish to swap), when you find the object set the object1 equal to that object. Next you do the same for object 2. Now, since you have a reference to both objects you can use a simple swap to swap the contents of both items.

Comment: No, I want to pick the cards randomly and swap it with the other cards. I have done up the picking cards randomly but i am cluess on how to swap it

Comment: You have 3 temporary variables that point to what ever objects you have in your list, in this case cards. One way you can do it is have card1 set to the first card randomly chosen, and have card2 set to the second card you randomly chose. Set card3's suit and rank = card1's suit and rank. Set card1's suit and rank = card2's suit and rank. Set card2's suit and rank = card3's suit and rank. You will end up with card1 holding card2's suit and rank, and card2 will end up holding card1's suit and rank. card3 is a temporary variable that will be disposed of when the method ends.